# Listen to Collection inside Backbone Model

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Let's say I am setting a collection on a backbone model and I want to listen to any changes on that collection.

Is there any way I can do something like this in my view -

```
  initialize: ->
    @model.on('change:collection:sortColumn', @render)

  render:(test) ->
    @$el.html(@template())
    $histContainer = @$el.find('.histogram')
    console.log 'clickable render'
    console.log test
```

?

That is, listen to changes to the models in the collection without taking out the collection and adding a listener?

Comment: Is `@model` a model or a collection? You say that you're "setting a collection on a model" but you show a snippet of view code that references `@model` so I'm a bit confused.

Comment: A better way to communicate would probably be to use some sort of event object/bus and then trigger an event in your collection and in your model subscribe to the event. That said there is a reference in the model to the collection which you might be able to use.

Comment: If you want to add listeners on collection, you can use model.collection.bind(event, attachFunction) to do this.